# Creating a VBA code to allow my Excel sheet to create a Dynamic drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio-code

TI have project where we have users in a summary sheet in column C I need to create VBA code to allow  to create a Dynamic drop down list in my summary sheet in column F so that when I select a name from that drop down list it opens the sheet that refers to that name.

This is all for financial records so we would see their sheet and all the information but only the sheet that refers to that name

For example, joe bloggs is in the dynamic drop down list I click on that name then excel open the corresponding sheet so that we can see that information

I have tried to create the code but I am very new to VBA so still learning, I am having issues getting it to run correctly.

I get errors, or nothing happens

This is what I have.

```
Sub CreateDropDownList()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

' Set the worksheet object
' Replace "Summary" with the actual sheet name
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2 (Summary)")

' Determine the last row in column C
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

' Set the range for the drop-down list
Set rng = ws.Range("G5") ' Set the desired cell for the drop-down list

' Clear any existing data validation in the range
rng.Validation.Delete

' Add data validation to the range
With rng.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=NamesList"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

' Define the named range for the drop-down list
With ws
    .Range("NamesList").ClearContents
    .Range("NamesList").Resize(lastRow - 5).Value = ws.Range("C6:C" & lastRow).Value ' Assuming names start from C6
    .Names.Add Name:="NamesList", RefersToR1C1:=.Range("NamesList")
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Please update your post with the code you've tried and specify specific problems you're facing. E.g. errors (codes, descriptions) and lines where they occur.

Comment: To start with, you are missing a continuation character ( _ ) for your line `.add`.  So it should be `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _`

Comment: I have added the code again since working on it and I am now getting an error 9 on line
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2 (Summary)")
as it says the sheet name is incorrect however it is not

Comment: Is "sheet2 (Summary)" what you see on the sheet tab, or are you looking at the project tree in the VB editor?  Likely `Sheet2` is the sheet's `CodeName`, and "Summary" is what's on the sheet tab (the sheet's `Name`).  You should use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")`